# Trying to make a search engine for issues

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec, gensim, information-retrieval, doc2vec

Our company has a lot of data that are issue which are stored in a database.We want to create a search engine so that people can check how the issues were previously dealt with.We cannot use any 3rd party api as there is sensitive data an we want to keep it as in house. Right now the approach is as following :-

1. Clean up the data and then use a DOC2VEC to represent each issue as a vector .
2. Find the closest 5 issue using some distance metric.

The problem is that the results are not at all useful.The problem is most of the data is one liner and some issue description.There are spelling mistakes and stack traces and other things.

Is this the right approch or should we switch to something else?
Right now we are testing on 200K data.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try a traditional, keyword-based search engine like Lucene? No need to share data with a third-party. Word vectors and Doc2Vec might be hot right now, but keyword based search has worked well for >60 years. Lucene will also allow for fuzzy search, which can help you with the spelling mistakes.

Comment: No ,not until now.Will do this and let you know.